# JSON data not passing to tableView Cell

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get the below code to pass JSON data to the table viewCell. I have confirmed that the JSON data is being captured and stored in the variable `downloadLenderRates`. But I cannot get the values to pass to the tabelView Cell. I confirmed that the cell identifier is named correctly and the swift file that helps manage the tableView cell is named correctly. At this point, I get no error messages and just a blank table when I run the app. I am not sure why!

```
class MortgageRatesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let mortgousURL = URL(string:"http://mortgous.com/JSON/currentRatesJSON.php")!
    var lenderRates = [LenderRate]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadJason()

    }

    func downloadJason () {
        lenderRates = []


       // guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: mortgousURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
                dateFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormat)
                let downloadLenderRates = try decoder.decode([LenderRate].self, from: data)

               // print(downloadLenderRates)

                self.lenderRates = downloadLenderRates

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return lenderRates.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LenderCell") as? LenderCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.lenderNamelbl.text = lenderRates[indexPath.row].financialInstitution
        print(lenderRates[indexPath.row].financialInstitution)

        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you set your view controller as the tableview delegate `class MortgageRatesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {`  and inside viewDidLoad method `tableView.delegate = self`

Comment: Add a print statement in your tableView cellForRowAt  method and make sure it is being called.

Comment: Btw no need to create the downloadLenderRates object. You can assign the result of the decoding straight to your array `self.lenderRates = try decoder.decode([LenderRate].self, from: data)`

Comment: don't forget also to set the `dataSource` if you haven't set it in your IB adding to the view controller viewDidLoad method  `tableView.dataSource = self`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LenderCell") as? LenderCell else { 
      return UITableViewCell() 
}
```

is very bad habit.

The `guard` can only fail if there is a **design** error which occurs for example if the developer forgot to set the class of the cell to the custom class. In this case you won't see anything in the table view.

This is one of the few cases where force-unwrapping is recommended. If the design is set up properly the cell is valid and its type is the custom class. Further use always the API `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` which returns a non-optional cell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LenderCell", for: indexPath) as! LenderCell
```

Comment: Thank you. this comment helped me fix a warning: prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers